# Copy values in one column to other rows in that column after partitioning data

Tags: python, pandas, split, copy, repeat

The table below shows the value column with value for the first row. I need to copy the value 100 to all other rows for id=1 and value =200 for all rows with id = 2

```
id  month  value 
1   jan    100   
1   feb    0    
1   mar    0          
1   apr    0         
2   jan    200    
2   feb    0            
2   mar    0
```

desired output:

```
id  month  value 
1   jan    100   
1   feb    100    
1   mar    100          
1   apr    100         
2   jan    200    
2   feb    200            
2   mar    200
```

Comment: `df['value'] = df['value'].replace(0,np.nan).groupby(df['id']).ffill()` ?

Comment: @anky_91, your solution works. Could you post it as the answer so I could mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(id_values):
    df.loc[df['id'] == i,'value'] = i * 100
```

Comment: This was a simplified version of the actual table. I didn't want hardcoded values.